# Nativescript - what's the difference between the package.json in the main and the app folder?

Tags: nativescript

There seems to be a package.json file in the app folder.

What's the difference between that and the one in the root folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote as originally posted [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2301)

> The package.json at the root is used to define
> the dependencies of the template, to persist some project specific
> information, etc.
>
> The package.json in the app folder is coming from
> the template. It has several purposes:
>
> - it allows us to have the templates published in npm.
> - it defines the
>   dependencies and devDependencies required to use the template -
>   nativescript-cli copies them to root's package.json during creation.
> - most important - this package.json is copied to native project and it
>   defines the entry point of the application (`"main": "main.js"). At
>   runtime this value is read and application is started from this point.

Answer (score 0):

Great question.
I didn't notice the second app/package.json

Project wise the only important package.json should be root one.
Unless nativescript does some underneath magic with the app/package.json, that file seems to be inherited by some git repo they use to generate the app folder, seems like.

But this is just a guess, Im not an expert in the framework internals.